# Weird glitch with disappearing status bar / nav bar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have an app that is similar to the photos app in that when a picture is displayed, it takes up the full 320x480 of the screen. Also like the photos app, when the user taps the screen, the status bar / nav bar fade out to provide extra space. Everything works fine, except I noticed one weird glitch. If I push the home button to exit the app (when the status bar / nav bar invisible), and then I push the apps logo to reenter the app, when the app reopens, the application frame gets screwed up, and the view that holds my picture gets pushed down 20 pixels (seemingly to make way for the status bar). Like I've said, it all works fine when I'm switching between views in my app, but when I push the home button to exit out, it messes up. Anyone ever have this problem before?

Comment: What do you mean by pushing "the home button to reenter the app"? Do you mean you close out of it, then tap the icon to reenter it or use the multitasking bar to reenter? A possible solution, always hide the menu bar.

Comment: @charlie yes that's what i meant I reedited. Not sure what you mean by always hide the menu bar, it only needs to be hidden when it fades in this particular view.

Comment: Right, but if you hid the menubar via `info.plist` even when the fade happens, then the error might be resolved.

Comment: @Charlie not sure I'm understanding. If I hide the status bar via info.plist, ie I manually go in and edit it there, won't the status bar be gone for the entire app?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What I'm saying is that if the status bar isn't really needed throughout the app, why not just hide it all together?

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same problem. When I in full screen mode press the home button and then returns to the app, the menu bar appears under the status bar when I return from the full screen mode.

Comment: @thejaz - I forgot to update this when I found the answer a long time ago, but looking through my e-mails I got this: "you have to make sure that you hide the navigationBar after the animation is complete (when the bars disappear), and unhide it before you make them reappear again." So even after you set the alpha to 0, after the animation is done, still make sure to set it hidden and like wise when you make it visible. Try that out and see if it works for you and let me know. I have a work around if it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have to re-set your interface code in this App delegate method:

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
  /*
   Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
   */
  }

Comment: I actually am utilizing this method and I've tried doing a lot of stuff to reset it to the way it was to no avail. I've tried resetting the wantsFullScreen, have tried resetting the navBar and statusBar to transluscent again, I've done all kinds of things to try and manipulate the view frame and 'reset' it.

Comment: when your app go to background and become "inactive" the System can release all your retained subviews (outlets and so) from memory, this is the pivotal point to investigate, because your app acts normally when your are interacting between its views (subviews fully loaded in memory).

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidAppear method try the following :

self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = TRUE;